# Tying Back to the Sendable Data Extension from _Bounce Data View

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit, bounce-management

In Salesforce marketing cloud, I'm attempting to tie back the _Bounce back data view https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_bounce.htm&type=5 in Marketing Cloud to the sendable data extension used for the email. Is there any way to do this? I'm looking at utilizing the TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID, but not having any luck.

Comment: How are you planning on 'tying it back'? Is this a SQL query to create tracking? Is it a lookup in the email? What is your purpose here and what did you use for your current attempt?

Comment: Sorry @Gortonington I didn't get a notification that anyone responded. We're looking to create one table, probably via SQL join. We're trying to essentially get all the subscriber data, including the bounce information, into one table that we can then connect to via API. However, when I query the Bounce data view, nothing populates in the TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID. What is this value? Is it something stored in Marketing Cloud?